# Thread safety of MyBatis Mapper with Guice injection

Tags: guice, mybatis

MyBatis-Guice suggests that instead of using SqlSession directly, we can inject Mapper instead. From https://mybatis.org/guice/injections.html

```
@Singleton
public class FooServiceMapperImpl implements FooService {
    @Inject
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Transactional
    public User doSomeBusinessStuff(String userId) {
        return this.userMapper.getUser(userId);
    }
}
```

This does not seem to be thread safe since mapper is created from one instance of SqlSession which is not thread-safe. (Ref: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html)

To make it thread safe, is this a better approach?

```
/** Thread safe implementation **/
@Singleton
public class FooServiceMapperImpl implements FooService {
    @Inject
    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public User doSomeBusinessStuff(String userId) {
        try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
           UserMapper mapper = session.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
           return userMapper.getUser(userId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You should be able to just use

```
@Inject SqlSession session;
```

with the following

```
bind(SqlSessionManager.class).toProvider(SqlSessionManagerProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(SqlSession.class).to(SqlSessionManager.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

which will create the SqlSession and associate it to the local thread.  You also shouldn't open the session manually if you're using @Transactional, a that should have already opened a session for you.